# Mysql: leaderboards for each of 200+ game levels

Tags: mysql, ranking, leaderboard

I need to store game user profiles in mysql innodb table. But there can be million of them, and profile record consists of 200+ int32 values and several others for in-game data. And I need to evaluate ranking of user for each those 200+ ints. 
i plan  to make it this way (for 121 level for example ):

```
select count(distinct(val121))  from ldbrd where 
   val121<$current_usr_val order by val121 desc
```

or using helper table {id, maxscore, minscore, count} to boost up speed.

I see two problems here:

1. table has 200+ fields of int. is it ok? Will such table be fast?
2. sql has limitation 64 indexes, so I cannot just make an index for each int field, but without indexes such search will be slow.

But I'm pretty sure that this task is common. I mean there are many games with hundreds of levels -  candy crush is most known I think. So how do people solve it? Thanks!

**---update**

I've decided to write profiles in binary fields (all those ints in one field) in one table and create another table for ranking evaluation: {id, user_id, level_no, score, timestamp}. But if we have 100000 users and 200 levels we get 20M rows in this table.
Yes, all fields have indexes, but it's too much for VDS with 2 cores 2.4Ghz and 2 Gb RAM. For example, query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leaderboard WHERE level_no = 153 
   AND score < 10000 ORDER BY score DESC
```

finished in 19 seconds! It's too much, moreover there will be many requests per second and every will need rank evaluation.

Also I have a thought to store a table for each level, maybe it will be faster this way (at least they will be much smaller).

Another thought - to generate say every hour top 100 for each level. It's pretty simple and fast:

```
SELECT score FROM leaderboard WHERE 
level_no = 156 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 100
```

But every one wants to know exactly his ranking. We can add 'rank' field however ranking evaluation in 20M row table will take very long time, server will be busy for others during this query, I'd like to avoid it. 
How do people usually do such things?

**-----update 2**

table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `leaderboard` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store_user_id` char(64) NOT NULL,
  `level_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `store_user_id` (`store_user_id`),
  KEY `level_no` (`level_no`),
  KEY `score` (`score`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
  KEY `lev_sc` (`level_no`,`score`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (id)
PARTITIONS 10 */ AUTO_INCREMENT=19999831 ;
```

I've finally partitioned the table and added (level_no, score) key. Was 19 sec, now: 0,017s. Pretty cool!

Still there are questions:

1. should I partition table in production? I heard people had problems with partitioning.
2. what's the best option - to have 500 tables - one per level, or one table 500 times bigger like I have now? Table per level work a little bit faster (0,048s vs 0,072s), but it's as long as I have several tables. Will 500+ tables work with the same speed?

Comment: What performance gains do you get by limiting the result set?

Comment: Do you mean last query? I takes milliseconds. but it's only a top of already sorted table by keys. the problem is ranking of every user

Comment: `count(level_no)` not `count(*)` might help - also do you have a composite index across `(level_no, score)` ?

Comment: thanks, I'll try, right now table is partitioning and busy. And no, I don't have (level_no, score), just tried to add it but mariaDB crushes. I think something with cnf

Comment: @Tertium I mean anywhere/everywhere. you don't always need to rank every user all the time, just 20-50 at a time.

Comment: see your point, moreover most of them may be "dead users". But how to limit query if I need ranking of player "player1" in level 100? I do in pseudocode "$score = select score from ldbrd where user_id=player1" and then "select count(score) from ldbrd where score < $score and level=100 order by score desc". Where to apply limit?

Comment: @Tertium Well, there's another problem. You should use one query. Post a Schema for more help.

Comment: Emmm.... can you rethink your ranking algorithm, so it will calculated on an absolute values (as time, levels number) instead calculating rank relative to other users? In such way, you can calculate user's rank when user do an action (on wins for example), and save his rank to special field. Then you will need simple one query to get this saved value.

Comment: @AlexanderRavikovich yeah, good idea. yet players worldwide think of ranking as a number of their place among others. who do we - devs - are to tell them they're wrong :)